# BeautifulSoup web scrape href issue

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper and am struggling to get the href link from a web page. The URL is https://fortune.com/100-fastest-growing-companies/2021/search/. I am trying to get the href pull all of the article links. Here is an example of an href I am trying to pull"

```
<a class="searchResults__cellWrapper--39MAj" trackerdata="[object Object] href="https://fortune.com/company/atlanticus-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/"><div class="searchResults__cellContent--3WEWj"><span><div>Atlanticus Holdings</div></span></div></a>
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re



URL = "https://fortune.com/100-fastest-growing-companies/2021/search/"
headers={'User-Agent':'mozilla/5.0'}
page = requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")

links = []
for link in soup.findAll(class_="searchResults__cellWrapper--39MAj"):
    links.append((link.get('href')))
print(links)
```

When I run my code, it gives me nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you have the most common problem: page uses `JavaScript` to add/update elements but `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml`, `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JS`. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  to control real web browser which can run `JS`. OR use (manually) `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` (tab `Network`) to see if `JavaScript` reads data from some URL. And try to  use this URL with `requests`. `JS` usually gets `JSON` which can be easy converted to Python dictionary (without `BS`). You can also check if page has (free) `API` for programmers.

Comment: Looking at the network tab in the browser's dev tools, the page is fetching the data from the following URL: https://fortune.com/wp-json/irving/v1/data/franchise-search-results?list_id=3159847&token=Zm9ydHVuZTpCcHNyZmtNZCN5SndjWkkhNHFqMndEOTM=

Comment: The data URL requires a token, which you will presumably need to find in the rest of the website's data somewhere, as it is likely the URL will be inaccessible when the token expires. I couldn't find it in a cursory search, though. Maybe someone else will have more patience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to add elements

But it reads data as JSON from

https://fortune.com/wp-json/irving/v1/data/franchise-search-results?list_id=3159847&token=Zm9ydHVuZTpCcHNyZmtNZCN5SndjWkkhNHFqMndEOTM=

and it can be used to get links

```
import requests

url = 'https://fortune.com/wp-json/irving/v1/data/franchise-search-results?list_id=3159847&token=Zm9ydHVuZTpCcHNyZmtNZCN5SndjWkkhNHFqMndEOTM='
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

for item in data[1]['items']:
    print(item['permalink'])
```

Result:

```
https://fortune.com/company/progressive/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/adobe-systems/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/salesforce-com/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/newmont-mining/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/lennar/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/kla-tencor/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/jd-com/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/jacobs-engineering-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/cigna/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/charles-river-laboratories-intl/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/advanced-micro-devices/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/paypal-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/netflix/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/alphabet/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/veeva-systems/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/align-technology/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/etsy/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/lululemon-athletica/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/trade-desk/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/emergent-biosolutions/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/hibbett/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/business-first-bancshares/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/marinemax/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/spirit-of-texas-bancshares/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/ies-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/brooks-automation/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/mid-penn-bancorp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/strategic-education/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/waterstone-financial/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/g-willi-food-international/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/marketaxess-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/ameris-bancorp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/shyft-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/smartfinancial/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/superior-group-of-companies/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/meta-financial-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/addus-homecare/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/metropolitan-bank-holding/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/1-800-flowers-com/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/fs-bancorp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/arch-capital-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/atlanticus-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/b-riley-financial/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/joint-corp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/quidel/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/acm-research/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/victory-capital-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/freedom-holding/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/staar-surgical/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/neurocrine-biosciences/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/kornit-digital/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/enstar-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/logitech-international/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/pjt-partners/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/mvb-financial/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/repligen/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/harborone-bancorp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/capstar-financial-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/ssr-mining/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/merchants-bancorp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/boston-beer/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/first-horizon-national-corp/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/lhc-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/mercury-systems/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/national-bank-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/facebook/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/monolithic-power-systems/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/perkinelmer/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/malibu-boats/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/svb-financial-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/first-bancshares/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/veritex-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/myr-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/mi-homes/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/slm/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/dow-chemical/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/fox-factory-holding/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/lgi-homes/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/take-two-interactive-software/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/paylocity-holding/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/alarm-com-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/ssc-technologies-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/stonex-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/century-communities/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/teradyne/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/nmi-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/virtu-financial/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/ubiquiti/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/scotts-miracle-gro/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/vertex-pharmaceuticals/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/medifast/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/epam-systems/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/medpace-holdings/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/green-brick-partners/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/leucadia-national/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/fortinet/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/appfolio/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/kinsale-capital-group/100-fastest-growing-companies/
https://fortune.com/company/pennymac-financial-services/100-fastest-growing-companies/
```

To get other information you may have to digg in JSON.

```
for item in data[1]['items']:
    print(item['permalink'])

    for f in item['fields']:
        if f['key'] == 'fgc_industry':
            print(f['value'])
        if f['key'] == 'rank':
            print(f['value'])
        if f['key'] == 'title':
            print(f['value'])
```

Url has field `token` but I'm not sure if it may change value. You would have to observer it in browser for few requests. If it changes then you may have to search it in original HTML.

After decoding base64

```
import base64

base64.b64decode('Zm9ydHVuZTpCcHNyZmtNZCN5SndjWkkhNHFqMndEOTM=')
```

it gives `'fortune:BpsrfkMd#yJwcZI!4qj2wD93'` and this values you may have to search in HTML.

Comment: WOW! This is so helpful, plus I learned something new! Thank you!